# A-Frame: mapping of 3d pointer events onto 2D canvas

Tags: javascript, aframe

Currently I have a canvas-based app in which I can drag and drop items (using fabric.js).  I want to use this canvas as a texture on an entity using aframe-draw-component and I also want this canvas to appear on a plane on which I can manipulate the items.  Anyone have ideas about feasibility ?

I was thinking I could create a function that uses canvas.dispatchEvent to map the click/move events while the ray is inside the plane which would involve calculating the intersection of ray with plane and transforming it into the 2d co-ordinates.  It seems like this kind of 2d interaction functionality could be really useful for creating rich interfaces that don't require 3d models so I'm wondering if there might be some 3d-party libraries to achieve it.  You feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking about two-way syncing, so that you could interact with the canvas directly and with a mirrored version in A-Frame? The `raycaster` component can give you 3D or 2D coordinates for where a controller is pointing, but dispatching events to your canvas-based app would be up to you (and might be hard).

Comment: Yes, I suspect it may be tricky or glitchy to dispatch the events, but that pretty much sums up what I want to do.  It is easier if I align the plane with say the xy-plane so I don't have to map a transform 3D->2D.   There's even a cursor that follows surfaces here https://github.com/jujunjun110/aframe-crawling-cursor that will be very helpful so I don't have to do the raycast-plane intersection myself.